# How to elminate "unsigned driver" install error for RNDIS driver on WInXP?

Tags: installation, driver

We have an application which uses the RNDIS USB driver, aka "Linux USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget" to talk to a linux based embedded device.

We have digitally signed (with a Verisign certificate) this driver for use with Windows 7.  This eliminates an "unsigned driver" error  message on install.

On XP, however, even a signed driver displays a "Linux USB Ethernet/RNDIS has not passed Windows Logo testing..."

This is, evidently, a driver developed by Microsoft.  I saw reports that this and other drivers were signed in SP2 and this broke in SP3.

The goal is to do an install of the driver without a warning or error.  Is this driver, or a compatible driver, available anywhere else?  Is there a way to get it signed through WHQL?

Comment: I believe th "Linux USB..." comes from the INF file, it is not really a driver developed by the Linux community. ???

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing:

> A company can choose to sign their own drivers rather than go through
>   the WHQL testing process. These drivers would not qualify for the
>   "Certified for Windows" logos, but they would install on 64 bit
>   versions of Windows and install without a warning message on 32 bit
>   versions of Windows Vista or Windows 7.[2] However, it will not
>   install without a warning message on Windows XP.[3]

I read something somewhere about how to get around this but can't find it right now. Can you not get it (or a renamed copy of it) signed through WHQL?